# How to make sliders more interactive in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, slider

**Aim**

After searching through stack overflow, I found out how to make the sliders interactive. But I want to make them interact even more.

Let's say I have a bag of apples. I choose how many apples are in there e.g. 10. Of these 10, if I say 6 are good apples, then 4 should be bad etc. Conversely, if I decide 6 are bad, then the good slider should be limited to 4.

**Attempt**

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)


ui <- navbarPage(
  
  tabPanel(title = "Bad Apples", 
           mainPanel(h3("A Few Bad Apples", align = "center"), 
                     sliderInput(inputId = "total", label = "Total Apples", min = 0, max = 10, value = 5),
                     uiOutput("goodApples"), 
                     uiOutput("badApples"))) 
  
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$goodApples <- renderUI({
    sliderInput("goodApples", "Good Apples", min=0, max=input$total, value=input$total/2)
  })
  
  output$badApples <- renderUI({
    sliderInput("badApples", "Bad Apples", min=0, max=input$total, value=input$total/2)
  })
  
}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Problem**

In my attempt, I can still move the good and bad apples sliders that do not agree with the total apples. Further, the good apples slider does not affect the bad apples slider.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not shown dependency between goodApples and badApples.

Try this

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$goodApples <- renderUI({
    total <- isolate(input$total)
    sliderInput("goodApples", "Good Apples", min=0, max=total, value=total)
  })
  
  output$badApples <- renderUI({
    total <- isolate(input$total)
    sliderInput("badApples", "Bad Apples", min=0, max=total, value=(total-input$goodApples))
  })
    
  observeEvent(input$total, {
    updateSliderInput(session, "goodApples", max = input$total)
    updateSliderInput(session, "badApples", max=input$total, value = input$total-input$goodApples)
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  
  observeEvent(input$badApples, {
    updateSliderInput(session, "goodApples", value = input$total-input$badApples)
  })
  
}
```